# Can I develop my own websites on my friend website server?

Tags: dns

If I buy a hosting (+ domain) service for the website of a friend of mine, and then I decide to use the remaining web space and mysql databases for my development and test...

is google caching my development websites (in other folders and sub-urls) under his website ?

What's the downside to develop on a server with already a production website.. ? I was thinking to create a tiny url linking to a www.myfriendwebsite.com/mydevelopmentSite.. in order to hide the real url.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't link to it or don't submit to google or list in a sitemap -- google won't find it.

But, you could also just use a robots.txt to tell google not to index it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard

Update: to stop google and malicious bots:

Put a directory in robots.txt using *, and then put your site in a hard to guess subdirectory of that directory -- also, don't keep directory browsing on.

Also -- don't link to it anywhere, but perhaps you can't stop others from linking -- in that case, only robots.txt will keep you out of google.  Malicious bots can get the site from the link.

Comment: ...or to hint malicious bots where to find it. I'd just not link it anywhere and leave it away from the robots.txt.

Comment: It could be -- it's probably a 301 Redirect, which tells google to follow it and treat the resulting page as the real page.  Use Robots.txt and google will not index.

Answer (score 0):

Your hosting provider may have forbidden that in his Terms of Service (mine has). Other than that, I'd go for a subdomain instead of a subdirectory (like mydevelopmentsite.myfriendswebsite.com).

Comment: I'm not going to use it for many websites, just for testing and development.. the tiny url is to not show the url of my friend to everybody (in case I want to show my temporary work)

Comment: You may get into problems if the endusers copypastes/links the URL somewhere in public web, then the bots will find it. Rather give yourself your own domain and do not profit from your friends.

Comment: well it would not be a profit, because I would pay it as well :) And if I use robots.txt to not index it ?

Comment: You can't use tinyurl to hid a url because it redirects.  The browser will change.  You need a proxy to do what you are trying to do.  If he's using Apache, set up a virtual server, and point another domain name to his server.